# Is there any math symbol \predeq in Latex? How to use it?

Tags: math-mode

Is there any math symbol \predeq in Latex? If yes, how to use it?

Comment: How is `\predeq` supposed to look like? Please post a picture of the symbol and have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: It is written here. https://bitbucket.org/tgregoire/latexifier/commits/48254efeede8a999b23a563a954a94e2. But I can not compile.

Comment: Well, you should be able to show us how it should look like. You can draw a picture if you like. You can easily upload image files here.

Comment: My feeling is that `\pred` and `\predeq` are typos for `\prec` and `\preceq`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line in that linked Unicode map shows:

`-precedesequal     8826  T \predeq`

See [PrecedesEqual on wolfram.com](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/PrecedesEqual.zh.html):

[image: PrecedesEqual symbol]

You can find that symbol in the [Comprehensive Symbol List](http://texdoc.net/pkg/symbols-a4), for example in the binary relations table as `\preceq`:

[image: Binary relations table]

Answer (score 2):

You also have curly versions and their negative versions in mathabx:[image]

in mdsymbol:

[image][image]

and in Mnsymbol:

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fishing rod, instead of the fish itself:[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)! Just tried it and it returned `\preceq` as the first result. It is probably a good chance to mention that a mobile version (android and iOS) is available as well.